# NPAPI plug-in in safari can not call js function?

Tags: plugins, safari, npapi

all.I want to call a js function to show something in my plugin.This is my code

```
NPObject* npwindow = NULL; 
NPError ret = browser->getvalue(mInstanceForJS, NPNVWindowNPObject, &npwindow); 
if (ret != NPERR_NO_ERROR) 
    return ; 
// Get window object. 
NPVariant windowVar; 
NPIdentifier winID = browser->getstringidentifier("window"); 
bool bRet = browser->getproperty(mInstanceForJS, npwindow, winID, &windowVar); 
if (!bRet) 
{ 
    browser->releaseobject(npwindow); 
    return ; 
}
NPObject* window = NPVARIANT_TO_OBJECT(windowVar);
NPVariant voidResponse;

NPVariant elementId;
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT([info UTF8String], elementId);
NPVariant args[] = {elementId};

NPIdentifier funcID= browser->getstringidentifier([funName UTF8String]);
bRet = browser->invoke(mInstanceForJS, window, funcID, args, 1, &voidResponse);
browser->releasevariantvalue(&windowVar);
```

when called  **bRet = browser->invoke(mInstanceForJS, window, funcID, args, 1, &voidResponse);**,Safari can not responsed.Is there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npwindow is already the window object; you're effectively querying for "window.window".  Granted, I don't know why this wouldn't work, but it seems a little weird.

That's problem #1.

Problem #2 is that you're using STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT to store the result of UTF8String. STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT doesn't copy the memory, so you could be in trouble if the function wanted to hang onto that string, since the string returned by that will be freed when your autorelease pool cycles.  Of course, that could also be a memory leak. Either way, the correct way to pass a string to the browser is to allocate memory for it using NPN_MemAlloc and then copy the string in. Then pass that pointer to the browser.  See http://npapi.com/memory for more info.

Problem #3 is that you haven't given us any idea of when you are running this code; it's quite possible that you are trying to run this code too early in the plugin or page lifecycle and thus it may not work because of that.

Then there is another question: What do you mean by "Safari can no responsed"?  Forgetting the grammatical error, I'm not sure what you mean by this.  Does it hang? is bRet false? Does your computer suddenly get encased in ice, thus halting all processing?  If the above is not helpful, please answer these questions and I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks taxilian.I alerted my code as you say.But it can only running correctly in safari 5.when running in safari 6,**browser->invoke(mInstanceForJS, window, funcID, args, 1, &voidResponse);** never finish. **info** is a string with XML format.

Comment: Please re-read my response and provide answers to the questions I ask

Comment: sorry, invoke function is running all the time,like a dead cycle. **What do you mean by "Safari can no responsed"?Does it hang?**---Safari is disabled and is waiting for invoke function. **Is bRet false?** ---invoke function is running,so bRet can not get a value. **Does your computer suddenly get encased in ice, thus halting all processing?**---All application can run normally except for Safari.

Comment: And at what point in the plugin lifecycle are you calling this code? On startup? In response to an Invoke on your NPObject?

Comment: I found the answer.My NSWindow is running with application-modal dialogs before calling this code,and this code will call **alert()** in the js function.but the alert dialog behind the NSWindow,I can not see and close it,so safari is disable.